# Making a matrix positive semidefinite

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have a symmetric matrix $A$. Is there a way to have a positive semidefinite matrix $B$, so that solving a problem $X$ with $A$ or with $B$ is similar?

I thought about doing $\alpha \cdot I + A$, so that alpha is big enough. Does it work in all cases? ie find alpha such that $\alpha \cdot I + A$ is positive semidefinite?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is problem $X$?

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is real, then there is a basis in which it is diagonal. Just use $\alpha>\min_{\lambda\in\text{Sp}(A)}\lambda$ where $\text{Sp}$ denotes the spectrum of $A$ and you will have a semi definite positive matrix. However, this does not mean that the solution of your problem with this new matrix if "close" to the real solution. It depends on what is your problem at hand, and what you mean by "close" (a metric could be used to quantify this).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Indeed my matrix is real, simetric. The elements Ai, j represent the similarity of the entries i and j, and the elements Ai, i represent the relevance of the entry i with the class (I am in a classification problem).
I mean by "close" the same solution ... in my opinion yes, if we increase the values of all the matrix equally.
What do you think of that?

Comment: You're not "increasing" all the values equally, you simply stretch eigenvectors (hence in specific directions). In your case, you have at least one eigenvalue of $A$ which is negative: making it positive change the direction any vector in the corresponding eigenspace will be mapped to.